# touch.view always UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm using the code below on touchesMoved to detect what type of object was moved over, and for some reason it's always a UIView. Why is this? I am touching a UIImageView and it still comes up as UIView, I assume it's because UIImageView is a class of type UIView, but then how do I detect if the object is a UIImageView?

```
if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
    NSLog(@"UIImageView");
} else if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
    NSLog(@"UIImage");
} else if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
    NSLog(@"UIView");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Image views have user interaction disabled by default. The view in question will therefore be the view directly underneath the image view.

You can enable interaction with an image view by setting its `userInteractionEnabled` property to YES.